# Do I need an SSL cert for a single page with MySQL DB call?

Tags: php, ssl

I have a one page site which (based on the $_GET{} variable) redirects a customer to one of two websites.

I am not collecting any sensitive information but am wondering if I need to get an SSL certificate for that site based on my sensitive DB data 'potentially' being exposed?

The get value will be used in a MYSQL query, if there is a match, redirect to A - if no match is found, redirect to B.

Comment: If you do decide to get an SSL certificate, don't spend hundreds of dollars a year on it.  Positive SSL is $9 a year, GeoTrust's is $10 a year.  http://www.positivessl.com/ssl-certificate-products/addsupport/ssl-positive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly you've not provided enough information to determine what your concern is, but my general answer is that an SSL certificate isn't going to protect access to your database from a security standpoint.

Your needs sound simple, and so long as you are careful to not allow any SQL injection coming from your query string variables you should be fine.

See more about the uses of SSL here: http://computing.ece.vt.edu/~jkh/Understanding_SSL_TLS.pdf

See more about SQL injection here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

I would worry about sanitizing the database inputs. SSL protects a middle man from capturing data, but will not protect bad code from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use SSL for this, assuming that the data your users are submitting is not something that should be private.

On the other hand, if they're submitting login credentials and you're then using this to decide where to send them, then doing this over SSL would be a good idea.

The processing that you're doing with that data should have no impact on your decision to use SSL for this or not. SSL is protecting data in transit between your web server and the user. It does nothing for protecting data between your web server and database, and does nothing to defend your database against attacks that might pass through your web server (such as SQL injection or denial of service).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're effectively filtering your MySQL data. As long as you're doing that, I think you'll be fine without the SSL certificate.